# C# mp3 changable progressbar

Tags: c#, progress-bar, mp3, trackbar

I want to make mp3 player (i'm using NAudio) and i want to make progressbar witch shows actualy progress of track and user can change it

I have 2 problems:

1. ProgressBar can't be modifited by user
2. TrackBar dont look as good as ProgressBar - I can use it to modifity volume, but no track progress

Please, help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ProgressBar is a control to show progress. It is not possible to enter some kind of value with it. You cannot use ProgressBar as a TrackBar. The latter one is designed for it.
If you don't like the appearance of the TrackBar, check out the internet for third-party components. Some will cost money, some are probably free.

Maybe this is what for you:
[Owner drawn track bar example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17395/Owner-drawn-trackbar-slider)

(note: I didn't downvote...)